# MVC 2 View Model Data Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, viewmodel

Here is my database Structure

**Languages**
LangID PK
LangName nvarchar(100)

**Category**
CatID   Pk 
IsActive Bit

**CategoryText** 
CatID FK 
CatName nvarchar(200) 
LangID Int

Language
LangID    |   LangName 
1   | English 
2   | French

Category 
CatID  | IsActive 
1     | True 
2     | True 
3     | True

CategoryText 
CatID  | CatName | LangID 
1 | Car |1
1 | Auto |2
2 | Chat |2 
3 | Plane | 1
3 | Avion | 2

I Use MVC 2 with Framework Entity as ORM.
First,I would like to have a render view like That in a html Table 
English | French 
Car | Auto
NULL | Chat
Plane| Avion

Here is my Linq Query:

```
 var qry6 = from Cat in _db.Category
                   select new CategoryViewModel
                   {
                       Category = Cat,
                       CatTxt = from lang in _db.Language
                               join ctxt in Cat.CategoryText on lang.LangID equals ctxt .LangID into jointxt
                               from endtxt in jointxt.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select endtxt 

                   };
```

My problem is  if I want to add something else in the View, I Can't because my ViewModel is encapsulate in a Linq Loop...
Here is what I Mean:

```
 var qry6 = new CategoryViewModel {
                    IDontKnowWhatTypeINeedHere = (from Cat in _db.Category
                                                  select new 
                                                  {
                                                       Category = Cat,
                                                       CatTxt = from lang in _db.Language
                                                               join ctxt in Cat.CategoryText on lang.LangID equals ctxt .LangID into jointxt
                                                               from endtxt in jointxt.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                               select endtxt 

                                                   }).ToList(),
                   LangList = _db.Language
        };
```

Is it a good idea to put a ViewModel into a View Model as I do in the example.

Thanks

Comment: I never use LINQ to be honest, but the first thing that popped into my mind is to use var query = from cat in _db.Category ... etc. Posted as comment as I'm not even near sure if this will work.

Comment: HI bastijn, 
I Use SQL To Entity. When I make a query like var query = from cat in Category, that will return a List of my Category Object generated by FrameworkEntity.

Comment: My question here is : Is it a good practice to  Encapsulate my View Model into an other View Models .

Comment: No, i don't think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what  I have in my controller.

```
            var query = new DetailViewModel
        {
            Lang = _db.Language.ToList(),
            ViewDet = (from gh in _db.Grp
                       select new MultiDetailViewModel
                       {
                           PKey = gh.GrpID,
                           Txts = (from lang in _db.Language
                                  join gtxts in gh.GrpText on lang.LangID equals gtxts.LangID into jointxt
                                  from fintxt in jointxt.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  select new MultiLangObject
                                  {
                                      LangId = lang.LangID,
                                      Txt =  fintxt != null ? fintxt.GrpTxt : ""
                                  })
                       }).ToList()
        };
```

Here is my View model.

```
    public class DetailViewModel
{
    public List<MultiDetailViewModel> ViewDet { get; set; }
    public List<Language> Lang { get; set; }
}

public class MultiDetailViewModel
{
    public int PKey { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MultiLangObject> Txts { get; set; }
}

public class MultiLangObject
{
    public string Txt { get; set; }
    public int LangId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my View.

```
<table class="tblMult center">
        <thead>
            <tr>    
            <% foreach (var lang in Model.Lang)
               { %>
               <th><%=lang.LangName %></th>
            <%} %>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <% foreach (var g in Model.ViewDet)
           {%>
            <tr>
                <% foreach (MultiLangObject gtxt in g.Txts)
                    {%>
                    <td> 
                        <%if (gtxt != null)
                          {%>
                               <%: gtxt.Txt%>
                        <%}else{ %>

                        <%} %>

                    </td>
                <%} %>
                <td>
                    <a onclick="CallAction('/Group/EditForm/<%= g.PKey %>',event)">Edit</a>

                    <%= Html.ActionLink("Manage", "/Grpdesc/", new { id = g.PKey })%>
                    <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = g.PKey })%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <%} %>
    </table>
```

If someone have a better way to do this please, post. 
 As bastijn said, I dont think encapsulate View Model into A View Model is the right thing to do.